# Crash NSManagedObjectContext in CoreData from iOS 12.2 and upper

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001beb420dc

```
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1beb420dc __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1bebbb094 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1bea9bea8 abort + 140
3  APP                       0x1008218d0 -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] (AppDelegate.m:686)
4  APP                       0x10081fbe8 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:165)
5  UIKitCore                      0x1eb4df020 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 412
6  UIKitCore                      0x1eb4e0784 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3352
7  UIKitCore                      0x1eb4e5f10 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1540
8  UIKitCore                      0x1eadaa104 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 776
9  UIKitCore                      0x1eadb269c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
10 UIKitCore                      0x1eada9d88 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
11 UIKitCore                      0x1eadaa678 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1064
12 UIKitCore                      0x1eada89c4 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 744
13 UIKitCore                      0x1eada868c -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 428
14 UIKitCore                      0x1eadad1cc __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
15 UIKitCore                      0x1eadadfb0 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
16 UIKitCore                      0x1eadad084 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 244
17 UIKitCore                      0x1eadb1d84 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 360
18 UIKitCore                      0x1eb4e4518 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
19 UIKitCore                      0x1eb0e0f0c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360
20 FrontBoardServices             0x1c191ed44 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 440
21 FrontBoardServices             0x1c1928754 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 256
22 FrontBoardServices             0x1c1927f5c __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 64
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x1be9e57d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x1be98a5d8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
25 FrontBoardServices             0x1c19590bc __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
26 FrontBoardServices             0x1c1958d58 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 408
27 FrontBoardServices             0x1c1959310 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
28 CoreFoundation                 0x1bef362bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1bef3623c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1bef35b24 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
31 CoreFoundation                 0x1bef30a60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1004
32 CoreFoundation                 0x1bef30354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
33 GraphicsServices               0x1c113079c GSEventRunModal + 104
34 UIKitCore                      0x1eb4e7b68 UIApplicationMain + 212
35 App                       0x100a35280 main (main.m:15)
36 libdyld.dylib                  0x1be9f68e0 start + 4
```

I tried to use CoreData in App, but the app crashed in NsManagedObjectContext. This happens only in iOS 12.2 and newer version. I asked in Apple Forums, but I haven't received the correct answer. This code works in iOS 11.0 and older versions -- I don´t know if is a new function of iOS 12.2 or my mistake. :(

Comment: To start, look at the line of your code where the crash report indicates the trouble is: AppDelegate.m, line 686.  If you cannot understand the trouble there, edit your post and paste in the code of -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext].

Comment: Hello everyone, I found the solution, the problem is that we are trying to do Heavy Migration manually, but iOS can do this, I found the solution in this website http://www.migueldiazrubio.com/desarrollo-ios-core-data-v-migracion-automatica-entre-versiones/